# Node express middleware coffee/stylus

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, stylus

I am trying to setup middleware compilation for coffeescript and stylus in my express project. My config is as follows:

```
coffeescript = require 'connect-coffee-script'
stylus = require 'stylus' 

# coffeescript
app.use coffeescript  
  src: __dirname + '/../assets/src/coffee'
  dest: __dirname + '/../assets/public/js'
  bare: true  


# stylus with nib
app.use stylus.middleware
  src: __dirname + '/../assets/src/stylus'
  dest: __dirname + '/../assets/public/css'
  compile: (str, path) ->
    return stylus(str)
      .set('filename', path)
      .use(nib());


# public directory
app.use express.static __dirname + '/../assets/public'
```

My (intended) assets folder looks like this:

```
assets
-- public
---- js 
---- css
-- src
---- coffee
---- stylus
```

localhost:3000/js/main.js <-- 404
localhost:3000/main.js <-- 404, but causes compilation

localhost:3000/css/main.css <-- 404
localhost:3000/main.css <-- 404, but causes compiliation

[Here is my project](https://github.com/kumikoda/node-skeleton/blob/master/app/config/express.coffee)

Am I misunderstanding something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend checking out [Asset Rack](https://github.com/techpines/asset-rack), which both will give you a consistent interface for compiling files, and has a lot of benefits around running automatically at server startup and fingerprinting to enable forever caching.